# What is this plant with spikes on its stem and leaves and is over 3 feet tall?

Tags: identification

[image]

The attached photo of a weed or plant is one of two that is growing in the spare ground beside our house.We have lived here for 33 years and this has never appeared before. It has spikes on the stem and some on each leaf. There have not been any flowers to date.

What is it?

Answer (score 3):

That is a young plant of [**common teasel**, *Dipsacus fullonum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipsacus_fullonum). It is a fairly common herbaceous biennial (occasionally short-lived perennial) in many temperate areas. It likes a good amount of sun, in semi- to disturbed places. It is sometimes purposefully grown for it's seed-heads, which are used in crafts, and it's leaves, as an herb. Here is a picture for comparison.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the single row of spines down the vein reminds me of teazle (teasel and other spellings) see: [Dipsacus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipsacus)

Comment: One of those plants like the occasional Mullein we allow to grow to maturity as they're kind of neat to watch grow and easy to control so they don't get out of hand. The flower balls are pretty pineapples of color.